# take user to app store if app is not installed on android/iphone

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am building an app for android and i-phone using titanium. One part of my app starts when user hits a link in browser(e-g when user types the link into browser and press go button, this starts my app) now the issue is if my app is already not installed on the phone i like to send the user to android/apple app store so that user may download the app and install it before hiitng the URL.

How to do this kindly help me as i am new to titanium. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Custom URL Schemes. Though this works if the app is installed.

For iOS, check the Info.plist file in the (project)/build/iphone folder and look for the CFBundleURLSchemes key. The value it lists under the array element is the name assigned for the custom URL. You can change that if necesary, but just knowing it may be sufficient for you. I think the default is basically your project name in lowercase.

For other who may need this question, the following example uses parameters that you can pass into the application.

Once you have that name, use it in a URL and add :// followed by whatever you want:

```
mybundleurlscheme://foobar?attribute=value&another_attribute=value2
```

In your app, use Ti.App.getArguments() to find out what was passed into the program. The caveat here is detecting the difference between a launch and pause/resume activity.

Last I played with this, a pause/resume would end up still leaving the same value in Ti.App.getArguments() making it harder to correctly detect a new launch vs resume activity.

A couple of pointers here:

Save a copy of Ti.App.getArgumets() for later comparison
Add a app listener for the 'resumed' event (NOT the 'resume' event) and check Ti.App.getArguments(). The value is not yet available during the 'resume' event (when app is preparing to resume) but is during the 'resumed' event (when app has resumed).

When 'resumed' event has the same value you originally saved, either the user did a pause/resume or the same custom URL was launched a second time. In my scenario, I could get by treating both the same but YMMV.
Here is a code snippet from a project where I experimented with this. It is from a few SDK versions back, so perhaps there is a better way now:

```
// Save initial launch command line arguments
Ti.App.launchURL = '';
Ti.App.pauseURL = '';
var cmd = Ti.App.getArguments();
if ( (getTypeOf(cmd) == 'object') && cmd.hasOwnProperty('url') ) {
    Ti.App.launchURL = cmd.url;
    Ti.API.info( 'Launched with url = ' + Ti.App.launchURL );
}

// Save launch URL at the time last paused
Ti.App.addEventListener( 'pause', function(e) {
    Ti.App.pauseURL = Ti.App.launchURL;
});

// After app is fully resumed, recheck if launch arguments
// have changed and ignore duplicate schemes.
Ti.App.addEventListener( 'resumed', function(e) {
    Ti.App.launchURL = '';
    cmd = Ti.App.getArguments();
    if ( (getTypeOf(cmd) == 'object') && cmd.hasOwnProperty('url') ) {
        if ( cmd.url != Ti.App.pauseURL ) {
            Ti.App.launchURL = cmd.url;
            Ti.API.info( 'Resumed with url = ' + Ti.App.launchURL );
        }
    }
});
```

For Android:
In SDK 3.0, there is No need to create a Custom AndroidManifest.xml, but rather simply open your tiapp.xml and find your   node, and make sure this is added in there:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MobileappActivity"
            android:label="MobileApp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                     <data  android:scheme="Mobileapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```